# Error configuring php 5.6 configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to install and configure php5.6 in linux. while executing the command

```
./configure --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --with-curl   --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-zlib-dir --with-regex --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip --with-zlib --enable-inline-optimization --enable-mbregex --enable-opcache --enable-fpm --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-libdir=lib64
```

I get the error

```
configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.
```

Even though the libmcrypt is installed.
    rpm -qa|grep libmcrypt
    libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64

I referred many links where they are asking to download the 3rd party repos 
    rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm but we have been asked not to use any 3rd party repos. So i downloaded the rpm file from net and installed it.

I am using Oracle Linux Server release 6.9.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt && sudo service apache2 restart
```

[Lamp install on ubuntu](http://blog.softhem.se/2014/04/26/ubuntu-1404-lts-install-apache2-php-mysql-configure-virtualhosts/)

Comment: and secondly we have to configure it on nginx not apache.

Comment: The question explicitly says it's for Oracle Linux, not Ubuntu. How does this help?